# Is this a valid way to use componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xtk

Im trying to use the xtk visualization library with react. Im running into a type error that says that default.a.renderer3D is not a constructor. Can anyone tell me why this is happening, this is my first time using react so Im guessing its a really simple mistake that one of you guys can help me with. Here is the part that is giving me a problem:

```
componentDidMount = function(){
  var v = new X.renderer3D();
  v.container='v';
  v.init();
  var randF = new X.mesh();
  randF.file = '../Assets/rgrid.vtk';
  v.add(randF);
  v.render();

}
```

Comment: It seems that `new X.renderer3D();` is not a class or a constructor function, nothing relative to react

Comment: according to this it is. could it be that I am not importing it correctly? 
http://api.goxtk.com/renderer3D.html

Comment: How did you import the xtk library ?

Comment: import X from 'xtk';

And I installed it using npm

Comment: Looking in the docs, seems like you should ```import 'xtk'``` and window.X will be available.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xtk

Comment: that doesn't really seem to be working either. Now its saying that X cant be called at all I dont think that is the issue. Im essentially running the example, and there seems to be an issue with the javascript not being able to connect to the dom.